# django jquery json deserialize

Tags: jquery, django, json

I have models for eg like this

```
class Model():
time=models.DateTimeField()
free=models.BooleanField(default=False)
user=models.ForeignKey(User) //it is my own User class
full_info=models.TextField()
```

than I serialize it:

```
data=serializers.serialize("json",Model.objects.all())
        return HttpResponse(data,mimetype='application/json')
```

and here is my jquery code I use to fetch it:

```
$.post("/url",data,
                    function(data){


                        }, "json"
                    );
```

And my question is how to write all information from jason about model?For eg I want that in one paragraph tag will be one object with all information about it. How I can do this? Thanks for help
Best Regards

Comment: Not clear, but am I right in thinking you need to know how to write the "view" code that returns the JSON-formatted version of the model object? If so, then its all basic stuff in the Django docs. Go read 'em.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the format that the serializer spits out (via your browser or shell):

```
[{"pk": 1, "model":"modelname", "fields": {"fieldname": "fieldvalue", "fieldname2":"fieldvalue2"}}, ....]
```

So it's a list of arrays with `pk`, `model`, and `fields` which is an array.

```
$.getJSON("/myurl", 
    function(data) {
        // data is [{},{},{}]
        $.each(data, function(key, val) { 
            // val is { pk, model, {fields}}
            $("#output").append("Object id is: " + val.pk + ' of model: ' + val.model);
            $.each(val.fields, function(fieldname, field) {
                 $("#output").append(fieldname + ' : ' + field);
            }); 
        });
    }, "json");

<div id="output">

</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed. Thank You Yuji again for help.

Comment: No no, thank you! for knowing what the accept button looks like.